# Check value on Firebase and start specific activity

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-activity

**Context:**

In my **MainActivity** I am trying to check if a value exists in the Firebase database, if it exists, it shows **HomeActivity**, but if it doesn't exist it will do something else. I mean, in the onStart () method, before the **MainActivity** is displayed and displayed to the user, the condition is checked. And if the condition is true, **MainActivity** should never be shown to user and **HomeActivity** is shown.

**Problem:**

I dont know why this is happening, but, if the value EXIST on firebase Database, my **MainActivity** is shown a few seconds and then **HomeActivity** is displayed. And what should happen as clarified above is that **HomeActivity** is shown to the user directly. I think that the method, `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is the problem here, but I wouldn't know why.

**Code:**

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Person").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(data.exists()){
                        Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }else{
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        if(user!=null){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegistrarseActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: It is a non blocking solution, the listener will always be added in the execution queue and it will not wait for it to complete and it will call the `onCreate` function. You can put this code in `onCreate` method before displaying the layout file so that it gets executed first.

Comment: I tried it but  happen the same thing :(